# Batch delete in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Is it possible to perform batch deletes using jdbc or native sql in mysql?

I have a set of unknown number of strings to be compared against a column and the rows be deleted. Is it possible to use Parameters in jdbc PreparedStatement when the number of parameters is unknown ?

Is there any other way to do this other than constructing a String containing the like clauses and executing it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it IS possibly, but it might not be worth it.

Prepared statements are really designed to handle cases where the query is exactly the same except for the variables.

They won't help you if you can't structure the query in advance.

So

```
delete from table where field1 = 'string1' or field2='string2'..... or fieldX='stringX'
```

Where X is not known in advance will run just as fast if the query is built up from scratch or if it's created as a prepared statement.

Let me know if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Thx for the response Brian. I was wondering if mysql supports some sort of native bulk delete like it does for bulk inserts.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you would be asking for more than just delete from table where some sort of criteria is met.  This will work on anything from 1 to an infinite number of rows.