# Delete multiple rows by id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, where-clause

I have a big list with id's that I need to delete from a SQL database:

```
B14260V;B14261;B14261V;B14262;B14264;B14264V;B14265
```

Currently I delete single items with:

```
DELETE 
  FROM `ixml_prd_map` 
 WHERE `ixml_prd_map`.`id` = B14260V"
```

It is somehow possible to batch delete items with the given list?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820549/batch-delete-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` operator.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM `ixml_prd_map` WHERE `ixml_prd_map`.`id` IN ("B14260V", "B14261", "B14261V")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `find_in_set()`:

```
delete from ixml_prd_map
where find_in_set(replace(@mylist, ';', ','), id)
```

`find_in_set()` returns the position of an element in a CSV list; it expects the separator to be the comma, so it you really have semi-colons then you need to change that, as shown in the above query.

A better option would be to provide your input as a proper list of values, as in:

```
delete from ixml_prd_map
where id in ('B14260V', 'B14261', 'B14261V')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM ixml_prd_map WHERE id IN (...your id list...)
```